# Is there an intuitive way of visualizing how a function that is flat at some given point can be something other than a constant function?

Tags: functions, derivatives

I can't wrap my head around how a function that is [flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function) at a certain point can be anything but a constant function, from an intuitive point of view.

Thinking of derivatives as "instantaneous rates of change", if every derivative at that point is equal to 0, none of them are changing, so none of them could ever take on a new value, meaning the function's value could never change. Imagining a particle whose movement with respect to time is defined by a flat function doesn't seem to make any physical sense because of this. In spite of this, non-constant flat functions exist, and I assume a particle could theoretically follow such a trajectory. Or maybe it can't.

So does anyone have an intuitive way of visualizing this?

Answer (score 1):

When you say "flat", what exactly do you mean? It seems to me that perhaps the issue here is a matter of definitions more than anything.

Derivatives do essentially give us the instantaneous rate of change at a point as you say, but by definition, for a given function $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, we have that for any $x\in X$:
$$f'(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$
This is the formal definition of the derivative, and can be visualized as a limit of secant lines (with one point fixed at $x$) that approach the tangent line.

Using your terminology, I believe by "flat" you mean that a function is flat at a certain point if its derivative at that point is 0.  This does not mean that the function's value does not change, but instead that the function value does not change at that exact point. Take, for example:
$$f(x)=x^2$$
For this given $f$, $f'(0)=0$ indicates that the instantaneous rate of change at $x=0$ is 0, but the derivative of the function, namely $f'(x)=2x$, is NOT constant, and thus if $x>0$, $f'(x)>0$ and if $x<0$, $f'(x)<0$.

To use your example with a particle, a particle whose position follows a "flat" function indeed takes on a single, constant value, provided that the function is continuous. However, I am unsure of what you mean by a "non-constant flat function". Your definition of "flat" seems to only apply to a single point of the function, and thus we cannot describe the entire function as flat, only points of the function, if that makes sense.

To put it another way, you could have a function that is flat everywhere, and in this case, the function is constant. However, consider the function:
\begin{equation*}
f(x)=
\begin{cases}
1,&\text{if $x<0$}\\
0,&\text{if $x\geq 0$}
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
The above function is flat at every point EXCEPT $x=0$. The derivative is not defined at $x=0$ and thus we cannot say that the function is flat. However, considering intervals on which the function is flat everywhere (namely $(-\infty,0)$ and $[0,\infty)$), we can indeed say the function is constant on these intervals.

Comment: Hello, the definition of "flat" I am using is the one given in the wikipedia page for flat functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function. A function is flat if at a particular point *all* derivatives vanish, not only the first one. No matter how many derivatives you take at that point, the result is always zero.

Comment: By this definition, the derivatives are only required to vanish at a single point. Regardless of this fact, the function can still take on non-zero derivatives in any neighbourhood of that point.

Comment: Yes, and that is exactly what intrigues me. How can every derivative be equal to zero at a given point, i.e. the instantaneous rate of change for every derivative at that point be zero, and also the function's value change?

Comment: The key to flat functions is that while smooth, they are non-analytic. Due to the fact that they are non-analytic, they are not quite so well-behaved at the points at which they are flat, which give rise to the characteristics that you mention. (Keep in mind that by non-analytic, we mean that the function that cannot be locally expressed as a convergent power series).

Thus, such a function would be piecewise, in the sense that the nature of the function would change depending on the domain.

Comment: Exactly... but is there an intuitive way of seeing how such functions could exist?

Comment: @jvf The wikipedia page gives an example of a non-constant flat function. Is there anything particular about that function which seems mysterious?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes! It's the core of my question. How can a function like this exist, given that the instantaneous rate of change of the value of the function itself and of every derivative at x = 0 is zero? To me, if a function has this property (being flat at a point), the only logical thing would be that that function were a constant function, since its value could never be incremented. Yet this isn't always the case, as the wikipedia page shows.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what it means to ask how a specific formula can exist. I think this is a situation where your intuition is just too rigid and needs to adapt; I'm not sure what sort of explanation is going to exist that could be satisfying.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I think the central issue to me is the "instantaneous rate of change" interpretation of the derivative. Does it seem logical to you to reason that a particle that follows a trajectory given by some function which has the property that at some point every derivative vanishes must not be moving at all? At the moment of flatness, there wouldn't be any forces acting on that particle. And no rate of change for that force to develop. And no rate of change for that rate of change for the force to develop, and so on. So there should never be any force. Does this seem reasonable?

Comment: @jvf That makes some initial amount of sense as a statement about the motion of particles in a particular sort of physical universe. But why should all mathematical functions model such motion? And ultimately the existence of simple somewhere-flat everywhere-smooth non-constant functions pushes against that initial sense pretty strongly - ultimately, my own takeaway is that that physical idea is actually surprisingly restrictive.

Comment: @NoahSchweber One reason is, and I may be wrong, but I can't see how the function given in the wikipedia page is mathematically incompatible with the laws of motion. So, at least hypothetically, a particle could follow that trajectory. Yet at the same time I can't see how a function like this could exist to begin with (my previous comment). A second reason is that the geometric interpretation of the graph of the function would lead to a similar conclusion. At the point of flatness, the slope of the tangent line is zero, the rate of change of the slope is zero, and so on. Yet there's the graph!