# Does "all derivatives vanish" $\iff$ "the rate of change is smaller than any function in $P$"?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, taylor-expansion, computational-complexity, conjectures

Let $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be $C^\infty$.  Suppose $f$ is not constant on any interval containing $x_0$.  Are the following two statements equivalent:

(i) All derivatives of $f$ at $x_0$ vanish.

(ii) The rate of change of $f$ at $x_0$ is smaller than any polynomial function.  More formally, if $g(h) := f(x_0 + h) - f(x)$, for any polynomial function $P(h)$, for any interval $I$ containing $x_0$, there exists $x_1 \in I$ such that for all $h < |x_1 - x_0|, 0 < |g(h)| < |P(h)|$.

**Background:** I am exploring [flat functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function) and conjecture that the "reason" their derivatives vanish despite the function being non-constant is that their rate of change is too small to be captured by any polynomial.  I am drawing on asymptotic concepts such as $O, o$, etc.

See also: [Is there an intuitive way of visualizing how a function that is flat at some given point can be something other than a constant function?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4272385/is-there-an-intuitive-way-of-visualizing-how-a-function-that-is-flat-at-some-giv)

Comment: I suspect this might be a duplicate but in any case this is an immediate corollary of [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem) which more generally says that the first $n$ derivatives vanish iff $g(h)/h^n\to 0$ as $h\to 0$.

Comment: @EricWofsey 1. I've read all the related posts I can find, and haven't found this point discussed.  2. Could you elaborate how that condition is equivalent to $g$ being smaller than any polynomial function?

Comment: Actually, as written, this is very false, since the inequality $0<|g(h)|$ in condition (ii) will definitely not hold in general ($f(x)$ could take the value $f(x_0)$ infinitely often as $x$ approaches $x_0$).  Also, you need to require that $P$ is not the zero polynomial.

Comment: Think about your understanding that exponentials grow faster than any polynomial as $x\to\infty$. Replacing $x$ with $1/x$ will tell you that $e^{1/x}$ goes to $0$ faster than any polynomial as $x\to 0^+$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first restate your condition (ii) to correct various minor errors which I don't think you intended:

> (ii) If $g(h)=f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)$, then for any nonzero polynomial $P$ then there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $h$ such that $0<|h|<\delta$, $|g(h)|<|P(h)|$.

By [Taylor's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem), the first $n$ derivatives of $f$ vanish at $x_0$ iff $g(h)/h^n\to 0$ as $h\to 0$.  (Alternatively, instead of invoking Taylor's theorem, you can just prove this directly by induction on $n$ by applying L'Hopital's rule to $\lim_{h\to 0}g(h)/h^n$, which tells you that the limit is equal to $f^{(n)}(x_0)/n!$ as long as the first $n-1$ derivatives vanish.)  So it suffices to show that this condition (ii) is equivalent to $g(h)/h^n\to 0$ for all $n$.  In one direction, if you know that for all $\epsilon>0$, $|g(h)|<|\epsilon h^n|$ for $h$ sufficiently close to $0$, this means $g(h)/h^n\to 0$ as $h\to 0$. Conversely, if $P$ is a nonzero polynomial of degree less than $n$, then $h^n/P(h)\to 0$ as $h\to 0$ (for instance, by L'Hopital's rule).  Consequently, if $g(h)/h^n\to 0$, then $g(h)/P(h)\to 0$ as well, which in particular implies $|g(h)|<|P(h)|$ for $h$ sufficiently close to $0$.