# Why can flat functions be non-constant (intuition)?

Tags: functions, derivatives, taylor-expansion, power-series, intuition

A [flat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function) function is a smooth function all of whose derivatives vanish at a given point $x_0$. Why can such a function be anything but a constant function? Intuitively if a function's derivative and the derivative of the derivative, ... are zero then some tiny step to the right the function hasn't changed, the dirivitive hasn't changed, ... so we are in the same situation again: It seems the function should be constant. Yet clearly, there are examples of non-constant flat functions!

E.g. If a particle has no velocity and also no acceleration and also the derivative of the acceleration, ... , are all zero, the particle shouldn't move at all!

This is a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4272385/is-there-an-intuitive-way-of-visualizing-how-a-function-that-is-flat-at-some-giv) question which received no helpful answer.
Thanks!

Comment: A zero derivative at a point does not mean the function does not change, it just means $f(x)$ approaches $f(a)$, as $x$ approaches $a$, faster than any non-zero-sloped linear function passing through $(a, f(a))$. It certainly doesn't mean that a "tiny step" to the right/left will produce the same number! Indeed, for example, $f(x) = x^2$ has a derivative of $0$ at $x = 0$, but the function is not constant on any interval around $0$.

Comment: The [example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function#Example) shows that intuition can be deceptive.